# How can I get the column of my sql database with $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql

I am successfull in getting the id as this is a page called shirt.php?id=2 which is a template to display a specific shirt based on its id. That works but in my database i have a column named "name" and that has the name of the shirt so "shirt2". How can I echo or grab this based on the current id of the shirt. is the code below too redundant? How can I simplify this?

```
<?php 
require 'inc/header.php';

$streamId = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:NULL);
if ($streamId) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM streams WHERE id = :id';
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $streamId));
    $listStreamEach = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}else {
    echo "not working";
}


$streamIdName = (isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']:NULL);
if ($streamIdName) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM streams WHERE name = :name';
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':name' => $streamIdName));
    $listStreamEach1 = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($listStreamEach1);
}else {
    echo "not working";
}
?>


<?php 
require 'inc/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Can you please provide an example of how your columns are set up, what data is in the table, and what you expect to extract from the table?

Comment: Sure its pretty simple. I have a table called streams and 2 items in there. The structure is : id,name.  Only 2 things. Id of course is auto increment and name is just a string.I want to extract the 'name' from the table and echo it to the page.

Comment: Are you getting an error with the code you have? I would not run `execute` if you already know `$_GET['id']` is not set and you're just querying with NULL.

Comment: if the page is only ever accessed as ?id=2 then $listStreamEach should already contain the full row where id=2, just access the 'name' value (try var_dump($listStreamEach). If you also want to be able to access the page via ?name=shirt2 then you'll need to look in listStreamEach1 (or rather, merge your code so that the lookup is based on either id or name)

Comment: `$streamId = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:NULL);
if ($streamId) {` this whole piece is redundant, you can use `if(!empty($_GET['id']))` and same with the name param also `isset` is slow as compared to `empty`

Comment: In the branch where `$_GET['id']` is provided, you never do anything (like print) `$listStreamEach`.

Comment: getting anything echo'd? getting any errors? you know that `name` is a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: No errors but on the second isset check the if statement fails and echos "not working". Im just wondering if since the page is brought up by its id couldnt it just work with say $streamId["name"]; but if i do that it says its an undefined index.

Comment: @anonymous I tried what you did and the var_dump did dump the information but now how would I grab that. Sorry if that is a very amateur question but i dont really know how. got this : array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(12) "Party Lounge" } }

Comment: no errors... use exceptions after your db connection declaration. You may just see something to the effect of `syntax error to the right or near 'name`

Comment: Hey everyone I ended up solving the problem. To access a certain item out from the assoicate array I got in $listStreamEach, all you have to do is make sure to return the query and then access like this: $name = $listStreamEach[0]['name']. the 'name' can be anything that the var_dump on your array returns.